# c# Single installation, multiple types

Tags: c#, installation

I need to create an installation that contains both the server installation and client installation, and prompts the user to select which one they want to run.  If it's server, there is a wpf application, some web services, and a SQL database that has to be installed (actually a backup needs to be restored), if it's client then only a series of DLLs and a single executable.  I also need to prompt for the DB connection information, login information, certain IP addresses, etc...

I've read up on CustomActions, but it seems that it's after the setup has actually begun, and your application is installed on the target system, when the CustomActions run, which is a bit too late for my needs.

None of the samples I've seen for the Visual Studio Set and Deployment project covers these types of requirements.  Is the Setup and Deployment project just not capable of this type of installation.  Does anyone know of any good sources for creating this type of installation?  Or should I be looking for a different installation solution, such as InstallShield or WISE?

Comment: you may want to consider the free tool InnoSetup.  It doesn't make msi setups, but the setups it does make are fully flexible because it doesn't have to work in the limits of the standard install process,  whether its suitable or not depends on your enviroment.  http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Comment: Please see **[this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1546916/129130)** for a summary of why keeping server and client setups separate is a good idea.