# how to check and stop uninstall in Wix installer?

Tags: wix, installation

I am developing two installers using WIX.
A --> Parent application.
B --> Optional application - but works only if parent 'A' already installed.

Some users uninstalls the Parent application 'A' accidentally, and opening application B is causing issue.
Expectation is, During the uninstall process of Parent application 'A', it has  to check for dependent application 'B'. if 'B' exists, then it should warn the user and exit from uninstallation.

I couldn't find a clue how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Products B[]  could install a shared component such as a registry value that indicates a product of type B  is installed.  Product A could then have an AppSearch/Launch Condition or Type 19 Error custom action that blocks uninstall if that component is found.

But I personally caution against this.  Blocked uninstalls and tightly coupled products are harder for users to service.  I would rather product B[] simple display an error message on startup that dependency product A is missing.

Comment: Agree. Blocking uninstall also opens for bugs where a product is impossible to uninstall (ironic bugs, always). Just from a pragmatic viewpoint. I would also say that it sounds like Application B is really a "Feature" - inside the main installer of Application A - and not a separate product at all, but that is semantics. Does sound like high coupling though. I guess it all depends whether Application B has its [own release cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546916/129130).

Comment: I have added that check in product B. if product A not present, then user cannot install product B.  

FYI, those applications are pretty old VB6 applications. since users are still not agreeing to make any major change, we stick to this. they are paying for this :)

Comment: Yes - sounds good. Pragmatic solutions are the only solutions when products are in the wild. I assume you are running applications that old on virtuals?