# WIX MSI Installer - Only 1 file and Choose Language, not one msi file per language

Tags: wix, windows-installer

need to make MSI in multiple languages - the documentation describes a way to use light.exe to create one for different languages - but is there a way to only have 1 file and for the user to choose the language on the first step (and to use the current language of the OS as default?).

https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/build_a_localized_version.html

Comment: [Just some comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546916/129130) for now (no time to answer). Particularly localization section.